# Test cin exception

Tags: c++, ios, exception, cin

I'm supposed to test input in a program with exceptions().
I've constructed the following code and I can compile without errors:

```
cin.exceptions(istream::failbit |istream::badbit);
    do
    {
        try
        {
            getline(cin,uppg);
        }
        catch(istream::failure e)
        {
            cerr << "Exception i inläsning";

        }
        ...
     }while(...)
```

The thing is.... I dont know how to test this code. What type of input can I write to get a failbit or badbit?

Comment: What do you want to test?  If you want to test your exception handling code, you could call `cin.setstate(istream::failbit)` which will cause an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this ([Error states of streams](http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/parallel/pgi/doc/pgC++_lib/stdlibug/err_7848.htm)) failbit generate upon wrong input sequence. For example you write something like: 
int n = 0; cin >> n; and input string instead of number.

```
    int main(void)
    {
        int n = 0;
        cin.exceptions(istream::failbit | istream::badbit);

        try
        {
            cin >> n;
        }
        catch(istream::failure e)
        {
            cerr << "Exception" << endl;

        }
        return 0;
    }
```